# What is the point of & in Rust if I can omit it?

Tags: rust

This is the code:

```
struct Foo { x: i32 }
fn bar(foo: &Foo) -> i32 {
  foo.x
}
```

It compiles. Then, I remove the `&` and it also compiles:

```
fn bar(foo: Foo) -> i32 {
  foo.x
}
```

The question: what's the difference and why it might be necessary to use this symbol here? Let me rephrase: why dereferencing is not syntactically explicit?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html

Comment: It says that content will be borrowed for the functions scope, I would not use `Copy` types to test these behaviors, please check: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f05095c45a2ccda6fe8b72d83642acaa

Comment: If `x` was of type `String`, the first example would not compile, so there's no real "can omit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo: &Foo` is a reference to a `Foo`, while `foo: Foo` is a `Foo` value.

The first signature declares that the function only borrows `foo` by taking a reference, the second signature declares that it takes ownership of the value.

Although both compile, and both are correct, there is a difference in how you call them and what you can do in the function body.

First variant:

```
bar(&foo)
// foo is still available here
```

Second variant:

```
bar(foo)
// foo is no longer available here; it was moved into bar 
// (unless foo is Copy, in which case it is copied into bar)
```

Furthermore, if the function `bar` owns the value `foo`, it is possible to move fields out of foo. This is not possible if `foo` is a reference.

Here is a demonstration with a field type that is not `Copy`:

```
struct Foo {
    x: String,
}

fn bar1(foo: &Foo) -> &String {
    // let y = foo.x;  // moving out of a reference would not compile
    &foo.x // can return a reference to field
}

fn bar2(foo: Foo) -> String {
    foo.x // can move x out of foo
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        x: "foo".to_string(),
    };

    let x: &String = bar1(&foo);
    let x: String = bar2(foo);

    // bar1(&foo);  // would not compile; foo has been moved into bar2 above
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d562c408a6b282cfb65f50cbaafa63ec)

Comment: "*Rust is strictly a pass-by-value language. This might surprise you since references play a big part in the language. However, references in Rust are first class citizens. They, themselves, are values that can be passed - by value - to a function.*" - [Ryan Levick](https://blog.ryanlevick.com/rust-pass-value-or-reference/).

Comment: @eggyal You are right. I'll better have that answer edited to use more appropriate terminology.